# Registration of Russian immigrants to England in late 19th century?

Tags: england, immigration, russia, 1890s, 1880s

My great-grandfather wrote a diary about his leaving the [Pale of Settlement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_of_Settlement) in the end of the 19th century to England.

The diary, or at least part of it, can be read [here](http://cabinetmaker.blogspot.co.il/).

I am trying to follow his path and get some genealogical data and historical references. You can see the work I started [here](https://posimenskydavisfamily.wordpress.com/).

Right now I am looking for immigration papers in to England, and any data I can search about him in England.

I Know he was a Jewish cabinet maker and part of the Machzikei hadath congregation.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  In order to attract potential answerers I would recommend including some more precise details about these ancestors.  For example, their names and the first record that you have of them in England, and the evidence that you have for them having emigrated from Russia.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I've edited your question to add a link to Wikipedia's article about the Pale of Settlement, and I've made some other minor changes to make it easier to read.  On your blog/site, you say, "According to the 1911 UK census (more on that later), Aleck Posimensky was born in Russia on 1888 and Leah Posimensky was born in England on 1892, so that narrows the arrival to England to somewhere between 1888 and 1892." I assume these are two of Michael's children?  It is helpful to put this in the question itself so people can see you have already looked at the 1911 Census.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how close to the end of the 19th century you are looking for, this may be one such database that Ancestry.com has assembled:

> [**About England, Alien Arrivals, 1810-1811, 1826-1869**](http://search.ancestry.com.au/search/db.aspx?dbid=1587)
>
> This data collection contains lists of aliens (non-British citizens)
>   arriving in England between 1810 and 1869. The records come from the
>   following National Archives collection series. These records were
>   primarily created as a result of various acts passed by parliament to
>   regulate immigrants and other incoming individuals.
>
> - [FO 83/21-22:](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/browse/r/h/C2990199) Lists of aliens arriving at English ports, August 1810-May 1811; 2 volumes of original lists created under an act passed
>     in 1793 “for establishing regulations respecting Aliens arriving at
>     this Kingdom, or resident therein, in certain cases”
> - [HO 2: Certificates of alien arrivals, 1836-1852](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C8866); 236 volumes of original certificates arranged by port of arrival
> - [HO 3: Returns of alien passengers, July 1836-December 1869](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C8867) (with a gap from January 1861 to December 1866); returns made of alien
>     passengers on ships arriving at British ports as required by the
>     Aliens Act, beginning in 1836; formerly known as Lists of Immigrants;
>     also includes some papers on the drafting of the Act, its
>     administration, and proposals for its revision
> - [CUST 102/393-396](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/browse/r/h/C11050767) Accounts of aliens arriving at London (July-November 1826) and Gravesend (October 1826-August 1837);
>     arranged by certificate of arrival number

Unfortunately, for later arrivals, like the "around 1890" period, the [Inward Passenger Lists 1878-1960 at FamilySearch.org](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Aliens_and_Immigrants_in_England_and_Wales#Inward_Passenger_Lists_1878-1960) says (with my bolding):

Those immigrants who came by sea between 1878 and 1960 may appear in the Inward Passenger Lists at The National Archives (BT26 and BT27). This large class of records is arranged by port and date of arrival but is not complete until 1890. **It does not contain details of immigrants who came from Europe** or the Mediterranean area of from anywhere by air.

Comment: thank you, my assumption is they immigrated somewhere around 1890